# Laravel 5.4 display cookie value in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, cookies, laravel-5.4

How to display a cookie value in laravel 5.4 blade by interpolation or using conditions ?

Somewhat like this:

```
    @if (Cookie::get('user_first_name') !== null)
      <a href="javascript:;" id="user_name">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ Cookie::get('user_first_name') }}
      </a>
    @else
```

Comment: Did you try: `{{ cookie('user_first_name') }}`?

Comment: I am getting this while using your code :  

user_first_name=deleted; expires=Fri, 07-Oct-2016 09:26:58 GMT; max-age=-31536001; path=/; httponly

Answer (score 2):

The way you suggested is correct:

```
{{ Cookie::get('user_first_name') }}
```

Given your comment, you probably did not set the cookie correctly. You may try:

```
Cookie::queue('user_first_name', 'John', 15);
return view('the-view');
```